# Elasticsearch like solution for max 1000 json files

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, indexing, solr

My application has to perform elasticsearch like querying on files in a directory.

At max, I will have only 1000 json files in that directory. 
Elasticsearch becomes heavy for this purpose. Is there any java library which I can use in my application which allows me to index the files and provides me elasticsearch like querying capabilities?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to check [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/)

Comment: Why would ES become heavy for this? You should check FS Crawler by @dadoonet : https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler

Answer (score 1):

You can use filebeat to pull those files and index them to Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat

It would ship the file by default line by line, each line as a single document in Elasticsearch.

I suggest you'll add a config in filebeat to tag/annotate the file content with the file system / directory hierarchy info, so that you can use that information when querying the data.